# "Upload" program online

Tags: database, oop, design-patterns, database-design

Noob question, but I have to ask:

I've always wrote programs that

- Starts
- Do their job
- Ends

For my next assignment I should create a program that:

- Starts
- Wait for fields in Database
- Edit them
- Create an output

For the editing and output there's no problem, but I don't know how to act for the first part.
I mean, I know I can just loop check a database and retrieve fields until it's empty, but how can I achieve the loop part without leaving my pc turned on 24/24?
Should I "charge" my program somewhere online? Where? What kind of services can offer me an host of this type?
What's the common solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to remotely start your computer over IP, and also to specify your program execute upon startup. However, if you require high uptime this is generally what people purchase servers or VMs via cloud service providers. If you want to save money and avoid keeping your main PC running 24/7 you could get a simple microcontroller like a Raspberry Pi which can act as your server.

Comment: I wouldn't mind to purchase a service that allow me to let my programs run peacefully.
Can you give me a name or two for that?
Where I can just upload my program and let it run autonomously

The best way to achieve this is with online VM, right?

Comment: @grutty Amazon Web Services (AWS) and Google Cloud are two cloud service providers you can rent VM space from and run your program with.